# Не работает библиотека Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Здраствуйте, недавно установил библиотеку Pandas (pip install pandas). Пишу код в pyCharm. Так вот, возникла проблема, pandas не работает, причём никаких ошибок не выдаёт.
Вот код, который не работает.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('source/train.csv')
df.head()
```

Я запускаю, программа секунд 5 работает и всё, при этом ничего не выводит. Путь файла уже проверил, всё правильно. Сам по себе файл не пустой, там 1000 строк.

Comment: Запускаете просто из py файла или из jupyter notebook? Если просто из файла, то `df.head()` нужно выводить через print.

Comment: Да, юпитер и вообще интерактивный питон просто по умолчанию печатают результат последней выполненной строки. Но сам по себе питон такого не делает, если хотите увидеть результат вычисления, то вы его должны его в явном виде напечатать. `df.head()` формирует датафрейм, но не печатает его, а просто отдаёт. Если вы результат сами не напечатаете, то как будто ничего и не произойдёт. Результат был вычислен, но потом выкинут в корзину.